# variable outside foreach is null but has a value inside it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this reactjs function to get data from firebase.
The problem is the postsArray. It inside foreach has the objects, outside it is null.

I add postsArray globally.

Any ideas why the return is null?

```
postsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    setPosts(prevPosts => {

        snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
            var value = subChild.val();
            value = value.postID;

            var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value);

            post.on('value', function(snapshot2) {

                postsArray = snapshot2.val();
                console.log(postsArray); // HAS THE VALUE

            });

            console.log(postsArray); // NO VALUE HERE.


        });

return [...prevPosts, ...Object.keys(postsArray).reverse().map(key => ({
    key: key, ...postsArray[key] 
}))];
```

Comment: `post.on` is an event handler and the code is synchronous, meaning the outer log likely runs before an `onValue` event is received/handled and you do the inner log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post.on` is async function that is why the value outside of the forEach loop is undefined for postArray

The solution here is to set state inside post.on. This however will lead to multiple setState and also keep adding the postArray data state.

```
postsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
      var value = subChild.val();
      value = value.postID;
      var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value);
      post.on('value', function(snapshot2) {
          postsArray = snapshot2.val();
            setPosts(prevPosts => {
              return [...prevPosts, ...Object.keys(postsArray).reverse().map(key => ({
                key: key, ...postsArray[key] 
            }))];
            })
      });
  })
})
```

A better solution here is to convert your callback syntax to use promise. I am not sure if firebase.database  provides a promise format so I will just show you the traditional way using Promise.all and new Promise

```
postsRef.on('value', async function(snapshot) {
  const promises = []
  snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
      var value = subChild.val();
      value = value.postID;
      var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value);
      promises.push(new Promise((res, rej) => {
         post.on('value', function(snapshot2) {
           res(snapshot2.val())
        });
     }));
  })
  const postArray = await Promise.all(promises);
  setPosts(prevPosts => {
      return [
          ...prevPosts,  
          ...Object.keys(postsArray).reverse().map(key => ({
                key: key, ...postsArray[key] 
            }))
      ];
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`post.on()` is an asynchronous event listener, your current code is synchronous. If you post more of your code I can help you restructure it.

What is happening is:

```
var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value);
var postFunction = function(snapshot2) {
   postsArray = snapshot2.val();
   console.log(postsArray); // HAS THE VALUE
};
// set the post on function. This isn't calling the function yet.
post.on('value', postFunction);
// No value here because the post function has not run yet.
console.log(postsArray); // NO VALUE HERE.
// the postFunction post.on is called so now you will get the console.
```

I would change it to look like this:

```
const addNewPostsToPrevious = (prevPosts) => (newPosts) => {
  return [
    ...prevPosts,
    ...Object.keys(newPosts)
      .reverse()
      .map((key) => ({
        key,
        ...newPosts[key],
      })),
  ];
};
postsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  setPosts((prevPosts) => {
    snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
      const post = firebase.database().ref(`/posts/${subChild.val().postID}`);
      post.on('value', (snapshot2) => {
        addNewPostsToPrevious(prevPosts)(snapshot2.val());
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any solution to this? I'd like to return the value.